# C# HttpHandler for Video Tag source for Android Chrome

Tags: android, asp.net, video-streaming, html5-video, httphandler

I have a C# HttpHandler which supports 206 and 200 requests for MP4 video files, which come from the  child of the  tag

```
<video id="Video-13181" autoplay="" controls="" preload="auto">
   <source src="https://www.somewhere.com/app/Content/store/2501-3464-5869/vid200.mp4"     type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

In Desktop Chrome the video plays but is requested with a 206, which the HttpHandler supports.
Here are the headers.

```
Remote Address:199.16.156.38:443
Request URL:https://www.somewhere.com/app/Content/store/2501-3464-5869/vid200.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:206 Partial Content

**REQUEST HEADERS**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:identity;q=1, *;q=0
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:UserName=; ASP.NET_SessionId=asdfq; .ASPXAUTH=18D12YADAD68E4F; CulturePref=en
Host:www.somewhere.com
Pragma:no-cache
Range:bytes=0-
Referer:https://www.somewhere.com/app/Content/ShowPage?cId=5600&Type=c
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

**RESPONSE HEADERS** 
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public
Content-Length:7128803
Content-Range:bytes 0-7128802/7128803
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 09:13:13 GMT
ETag:"NuvYZ1qgzEZ4ghc/ZSVWKA=="
Expires:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 09:13:18 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 11 Aug 2014 09:46:30 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie:CulturePref=en; expires=Thu, 13-Aug-2015 09:13:13 GMT; path=/
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

When this same video is loaded in Android/Chrome it does not work, even though 206 is supported.  The MP4 file will play on Android/Chrome when the MP4 is sitting in the folder on the website with a Video tag which references the file directly.  But when it comes thru the handler it does not work.  The HttpHandler will serve the video on Safari on IPad/IPhone, and even Android/Firefox, but not on Android/Chrome.  This must be made to work.  Perhaps it could be some type of permissions issue, as I am sure the encoding is correct as it plays when the MP4 is referenced directly.  Here are the HTTP headers for Android/Chrome

```
Remote Address:199.16.156.38:443
Request URL:https://www.somewhere.com/app/Content/store/2501-3464-5869/vid200.mp4
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

**REQUEST HEADERS**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:UserName=; ASP.NET_SessionId=wpap05b; .ASPXAUTH=CE2D3E02B0EE4; CulturePref=en
Host:www.somewhere.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:Referer:https://www.somewhere.com/app/Content/ShowPage?cId=5600&Type=c
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; SGP311 Build/10.4.1.B.0.109) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.128 Safari/537.36

**RESPONSE HEADERS**
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public
Content-Length:7128803
Content-Type:video/mp4
Date:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 09:19:34 GMT
ETag:"NuvYZ1qgzEZ4ghc/ZSVWKA=="
Expires:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 09:19:40 GMT
Last-Modified:Mon, 11 Aug 2014 09:46:30 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Set-Cookie:CulturePref=en; expires=Thu, 13-Aug-2015 09:19:35 GMT; path=/
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

why won't this work.

I can however not only get the MP4 to play when referenced from the  child of the  tag as a direct file

```
<video id="Video-13181" autoplay="" controls="" preload="metadata">
   <source src="/pathToActualVideoFileOnWebsite/vid200.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I can even reference a file from a ASHX handler and it works

```
<video id="Video-127" autoplay="" controls="" preload="metadata">
    <source src="/virtualdir/Reports/Video.ashx?VideoId=vid200" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

with the Video.ashx.cs

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;
    var fileParam = "vid200.mp4";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/."), "Reports\\" + fileParam);
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
    int len = (int)file.Length, bytes;
    response.AppendHeader("content-length", len.ToString());
    response.ContentType = "video/mpeg";  //also tried "video/mp4"
    response.TransmitFile(file.Name);
}
```

the HTTP headers in this case were:

```
**Remote Address:199.16.156.38:443
Request URL:https://www.somesite.com/virtualdir/Reports/Video.ashx?VideoId=CCV0280
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK**

**REQUEST HEADERS**
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:UserName=; ASP.NET_SessionId=vl0n4e33guh; .ASPXAUTH=D2492E821FA4DF87;     CulturePref=en
Host:www.i-coach.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://www.somesite.com/virtualdir/Content/jqmCCV0280
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.3; SGP311 Build/10.4.1.B.0.109) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.128 Safari/537.36

**RESPONSE HEADERS**
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:2780949
Content-Type:video/mpeg
Date:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 15:30:21 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

I have also tried to gzip the stream as it seems that Android/Chrome requests that, but it made no difference.  I also used the XMLHttpRequest Object to GET the file as a blob and set the SRC of the video to a blob, this didn't work either, neither in standard format or gzip.  Really stuck.  Let me know if you need any more info.  I thought it could be a permissions type of error, but when it is it doesn't work on any browser.  In this case it works on everything but Chrome on Android

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging it appears that when you serve Video Files with an HttpHandler
to Chrome on Android.  The device will accept the standard file with a 200, even though Range Requests with 206 was supported.  The issue was that if the HttpHandler calls anything from the httpContext then it will fail.

In this case the following 2 calls where being made in the HttpHandler before delivering the file:

```
httpContext.Session["x"]
httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

When these where made the File would not be delivered.  This maybe different for other HTML tags which request content from Handlers but this was when the request was made by the video tag...

```
<video id="Video-3" autoplay controls preload="auto">
    <source src="./MyHttpHandler.ashx?c=3&f=video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

this was after investigation of different mp4 encodings, trying Talifun.StaticFileHandler and other handlers which support Range-Requests either 200 or 206.

Every other browser was fine with these items being read out of the HttpContext, including Firefox on Android and Safari on IPad.